# setting the background of a custom tableviewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uicolor

I want to set the background of my customTableViewCell to black. After some searching the most common answer was to do this in my CellForRowAtIndex.

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

But it didn't helped. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you put this outside of `if (cell == nil)` ? If yes, I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as follows and keep one thing in mind whatever subview you are adding on contentview should have clearcolor.As in my case I have default textLabel so I set it as clear color.

```
 cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

set background as follow :
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];